# a javascript countdown timer for quiz

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I have developed a quiz.It works with a javascript countdown.The countdown works fine but works also when you submit the form.The use of the script supposed to work only when the time exceeds.How can i disable the script when i submit and let it work only when you run out of time?Code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 6;
var redirect = "http://www.apphp.com";

function countDown(){
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
if(count > 0){
    count--;
    timer.innerHTML = "This page will redirect in "+count+" seconds.";
    setTimeout("countDown()", 1000);
}else{
    window.location.href = redirect;
}
}
</script>

Our webpage has beed moved. Please update your bookmarks for the new     site.
<br>

<span id="timer">
<script type="text/javascript">countDown();</script>
</span>

<a class="form_submit ss_btn" href="#" onclick="return SST.form_submit(widget_50467774);"> Submit </a>
```

Comment: Where is the submit part?

Comment: <a class="form_submit ss_btn" href="#" onclick="return SST.form_submit(widget_50467774);">
Submit
</a>

Comment: What does "works also whenyou submi the form" does SST.form_submit do an ajax call?

Comment: Don't know for sure..I'm manipulating a quiz given in a shortstack app.
I don't think i can edit all inner files.There is my App >>

https://1.shortstack.com/W4fmDl?ga=1.147409271.1367173926.1461659282

Comment: Submission takes you to a html-3 minisite but after a minute javascript acts and finally redirects you to where it says...sorry out of time..

Comment: See my answer. You likely need my second part too

Comment: code is copied from here and just added
http://www.apphp.com/index.php?snippet=javascript-redirect-with-timer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the form submit is an ajax call, you can clear the timeout like this :

```
var tId;
.
.
.
tId = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
.
.
clearTimeout(tId);  // stop from running again
```

Like here:

```
var count = 6;
var redirect = "http://www.apphp.com";
var tId;

function countDown() {
  var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
  if (count > 0) {
    count--;
    timer.innerHTML = "This page will redirect in " + count + " seconds.";
    tId = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
  } else {
    window.location.href = redirect;
  }
}
```

Since you likely have no access to the SST.form_submit, you then add this inline:

```
<a class="form_submit ss_btn" href="#"
onclick="clearTimeout(tId); return SST.form_submit(widget_50467774);"> Submit </a>
```

or if there is a test in the submission that blocks the submission (failure to fill something in):

```
<a class="form_submit ss_btn" href="#"
onclick="var ok = SST.form_submit(widget_50467774); if (ok) clearTimeout(tId); return ok;"> Submit </a>
```

Comment: "...form_submit = function() { // whatever that looks like"
what should i put here?
_____________________________________________
something like that? : form_submit ss_btn = function() { return SST.form_submit(widget_50530289)

Comment: No, ignore it. It was if you had access to the SST code, which you do not. Just use the code in the link and add the `var tID;` and add the `tId=setTimeout..`

Comment: Final feedback..The script kills time alright..Freezes the time you submit.The problem is that in stis script :{ return SST.form_submit(widget_50530289) the widget is generated by the app its self so i quess there is not much to do.

Comment: We can add to the onclick so I am not sure what is stopping you? Is the submit link not written by you?

Comment: i can only add code to overight  in  some cases the exist code but each time  a player takes a quiz the platform generates different widget number .So countdown freezes but i get no submission data in email.

Comment: I am not familiar with your platform. Perhaps you can ask them or in their forum?

Comment: i will..Sorry for taking your time .one last question.Can i put sove javascript only to disable countdown?? something like this :
<a class="form_submit ss_btn" 
onclick="clearTimeout(tId);
And leave the rest to the platform.

Comment: Try and see. Otherwise add `$(function() { $("form_submit").on("click",function() { clearTimeout(tId) });});` to the script along with the var tId and tId=setTimeout...